# How to set NavigationIcon on Toolbar ("java.lang.ClassCastException" error)

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, androidx

I want to have a back button on my toolBar, but I am stuck with this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot
>   be cast to android.widget.Toolbar

This is my xml file:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="InstaPF for Instagram"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:id="@+id/Textbar"/>


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Code:

```
        Toolbar mToolbar = (android.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Does somebody also know to icon of the back button. I have this set just for testing: `R.drawable.ic_menu_share`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import in your code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

instead of `android.widget.Toolbar`

Also remove the casting:

```
//Toolbar mToolbar = (android.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
Toolbar mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a `R.drawable` for a back icon?

Comment: Export your favorite icons from https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: Hi @VineTube  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.